# admin_post hook not called / callback not executed

Tags: forms

I'm trying to process a form, and struggling with admin_post.php. Here is the relevant section of my plugin PHP code :

```
add_action('admin_post_cs_submit', 'submit_test');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_cs_submit', 'submit_test');

function submit_test() {
    wp_redirect('https://www.google.com');
    exit();
}
```

And here is the cURL command I am using for testing :

```
curl --location 'http://localhost/wp-install-directory/wp-admin/admin_post.php' --form 'action="cs_submit"'
```

The response is my Wordpress 404 page. Replacing the code of `submit_test` with an `echo` yields no result either. It seems that the hook is not called. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your URL is incorrect. `admin_post.php` should be `admin-post.php`.